# Visual Studio 2022 Memory 1 Debug Window not working with Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to verify the memory layout of one of my structs. I'm using the Memory 1 Debug Window (Debug -> Windows -> Memory -> Memory 1) and it works fine for my Blazor WebAssembly hosted server project (ASP.Net Core 6). But in the client project (Blazor WebAssembly) it can't find any variable address I enter.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Example
{
    [JsonInclude][FieldOffset(0)]public byte Byte0;
    [JsonInclude][FieldOffset(1)]public byte Byte1;
    [JsonInclude][FieldOffset(2)]public byte Byte2;
    [JsonInclude][FieldOffset(3)]public byte Byte3;
}
```

In one of my pages I have this:

```
public static Example thing;
```

If I hit a breakpoint in that page and enter "&thing" in the Memory 1 Window, it says "Unable to evaluate the expression". I expected to be able to see it, like in the server project.

Is this a limitation of Blazor WebAssembly, and is there another way to see the memory of one of my variables?